# iPhone App has large memory footprint on startup

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

If I put a breakpoint on my first line of code from main function, I see in the activity monitor 17MB of memory for my app. Do you have any idea why the memory usage is so high without anything loaded? (Maybe the OS is loading many things, but not me)

This memory usage has almost the same size as the app executable. Is the executable fully loaded at startup?
How can I reduce the initial memory size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't look at the activity monitor, use Instruments (Profile, allocations).

Answer (score 2):

I think the fact that it's the same size as your app bundle is probably just a coincidence because the whole bundle is not loaded into memory on startup.

As CocoaFu said, use the allocations tool to see how much memory your app is allocating. It will be much smaller than the activity monitor tool because it does not include memory used by OpenGL (which backs all user interface elements).

Most likely, you actual allocations are quite small (a MB or less) while the other 16 or so MB are all of the interface elements of your app being created by UIKit (i.e. your navigation controller, various view controllers, buttons, whatever). Note that on an iPhone 4 or iPod touch 4th gen, the OpenGL allocations (i.e. the difference between the allocations tool and activity monitor tool) will be roughly two to four times the size than on earlier models because the screen has 4 times the resolution so all UI elements are larger.

Comment: My app bundle has 400MB. My executable has 17MB and code and data share same memory. Maybe the activity monitor is correct...

Comment: Ahh, I misread. I thought you said app bundle. I suppose it probably does load the entire executable into memory. That is an incredibly massive executable though, may I ask what type of app it is?

Comment: Also, I'm curious how much memory are you using according to the allocations tool.

Comment: It's a game. I can't use allocation tool. App crashes while using it every time.

Comment: Is that when using a real device? If so, try when using the simulator since you'll have the full power of your Mac behind it. In any case, I think the only way you're going to reduce that footprint is to reduce the size of your binary. Any ideas why the binary is so large? For comparison, my fairly complex music streaming app's binary with many 3rd party libraries and hundreds of classes is only 5.7 MB.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.. In that case I'm not sure there's anything you can do short of moving to a smaller engine. I will say though, that as long as you keep your memory in check after the app launch, 17 MB is well within spec for an app, especially on devices with 256 or 512MB of RAM. I think all OpenGL allocations from the UI included, my app uses somewhere around 30-35MB and users on even older devices with 128MB RAM have no problem running it. You should be good even up into the 40s or 50s total (as shown by activity monitor), even higher on the iPhone 4.

Comment: My memory footprint is around 120 MB.